# How can I run ctags in a large code base?

Tags: linux, vim, cygwin, vi, ctags

Assuming I have a code directory structure as follows:

```
/top  
   /second  
       /core  
           a.pl  
           b.pl  
           c.pl  
       /common  
           d.pl  
           e.pl  
       /util  
           f.pl  
           g.pl  
           h.pl
```

Where should I run the `ctags` so that I can jump to function definitions via `vi`?

For example I had:

```
/dir
   /perl  
      a.pl
```

and I run in `dir` the command `ctags -R perl` but in `a.pl` I could not jump to a function definition that existed in the same file.
If I did `ctags -R .` **inside** the `perl` directory it worked.

So I can not understand the pattern. Should I run `ctags` in `core, common,util`? What if my code base is huge? Would I really need to run it in each directory?

Comment: Which ctags are you running? If you are running Exuberant Ctags, they have an [FAQ about exactly this topic](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/faq.html#15).

Comment: Since you use ctags in Vim, I recommend you not to deal with ctags manually, but try plugin Indexer (http://goo.gl/lNrB5) which painlessly generates tags for the whole project(s) and keeps tags up-to-date. You can also check my answer to this question http://goo.gl/dMavX for a bit more details.

Comment: @msw:I don't know.Those installed in cygwin.How do I check this?

Comment: @Cratylus on my system `ctags --version` says "Exuberant Ctags...". Based on the [Cygwin manifest](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=ctags%2Fctags-5.8-1&grep=ctags) it appears likely that that's what you've got too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you would use just one `tags` file located in the root directory of your project.

For example, to tag the whole of Vim's own source code, located in `~/src/vim-7.3`, you navigate to that directory and generate the tags file there.

```
$ cd ~/src/vim-7.3
$ ctags -R
```

That's all.

You can do the same from inside Vim, of course. Start Vim and then type:

```
:cd ~/src/vim-7.3
:!ctags -R
```

Check that you have the correct `'tags'` setting. Default is `./tags,tags`, meaning Vim will look for a `tags` file in the current directory.

Make sure to read [`:h 'tags'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27tags%27) in its entirety. You can instruct Vim to look for `tags` files deep in the directory tree by giving patterns containing wildcards.

One more thing: For this approach to work, Vim's current working directory must remain at the root at all times. If you have some option like `'autochdir'` set or constantly switch directories yourself, then the `tags` obviously won't be found.

Comment: When I type `:h 'tags'` I get: `E433: No tags file
E149: Sorry, no help for 'tags'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
`

Comment: @Cratylus That sounds like you have a serious problem with your runtime files. Does `:help` work at all?

Comment: If I type `:help` I get: `E433: No tags file
E149: Sorry, no help for help.txt
Press ENTER or type command to continue
`

Comment: Also `set syntax on` does not work.In case it means something.

Comment: @Cratylus I'm sorry but that means you haven't installed Vim correctly. Can you reinstall? No need to bother with ctags until your Vim is up and running.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your latest update.How do I know that `Vim's current working directory is  at the root at all times`

Comment: @Cratylus In my example, `:pwd` should output `/home/glts/src/vim-7.3` at all times. That's the root directory of the project and that's were the `tags` file is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30219/discussion-between-glts-and-cratylus)

Comment: :If you have time could you please check out my other question since you also worked on `cygwin` recently :) http://superuser.com/questions/597293/apache-package-in-cygwin-does-not-seem-to-work-error-logs-are-also-empty

Answer (score 9):

Your `tags` file should be generated in the first common ancestor of your code (that would be `second`, in your case) with `$ ctags -R .`.

I'd suggest you add this line to your `~/.vimrc` in order to make Vim always find your `tags` file, no matter where you are in your project and no matter what the "current directory" is:

```
set tags=./tags;/,tags;/
```

It works like the one in @glts's answer with an interesting twist: because of the `;/` part, Vim looks up and up until `/` for a `tags` file. Supposing you are editing `g.pl`, Vim will correctly use your `tags` file located in `second`.

```
:h tags
:h ctags
```

Comment: Nice guess with the `,/` but it doesn't work like that in Vim. There's no walking up the directory tree, unfortunately. And you can actually use `ctags -R` to mean `ctags -R .`!

Comment: It's `;/` not `,/` (the `/` is not required but more explicit so I keep it here) and yes it works like that. See `:h file-searching`, specifically the "upward search" part.